# Using Groovy find String from Exclusion List

Tags: groovy

In groovy, I want to search text (which is typically an xml structure) and find an occurrence of the ignore list.

For example:
My different search data requests are (reduced for clarity, but most are large):

```
<CustomerRQ field='a'></CustomerRQ>
<AddressRQ field='a'></AddressRQ>
```

My ignore list is:

```
CustomerRQ
CustomerRS
```

Based on the above two incoming requests of "customer" and "address", I want to ignore "Customer" since it's in my ignore list, but I want to identify "address" as a hit.

The overall intent is to use this for logging.  I want to not log some incoming requests based on my "ignore" list, but all others will be logged.

Here's some pseudo code that may be on the right track but not really.

```
def list = ["CustomerRQ", "CustomerRS"]
println(list.contains("<CustomerRQ field='a'>"))
```

I'm not sure, but I think a closure will work in this case, but learning the groovy ropes here.  Maybe a regexp will work as well.  But the importance is to search in the incoming string (indexOf, exists...) across all of my exclusions list.

Comment: It's really hard to see what you want....can you edit the question with a clearer explanation of what you are trying to achieve?  You have a tiny piece of xml and you want to see if the nodename of that xml is in your ignorelist?

Comment: Thanks @DaveNewton I'm a new guy to socially working with stackoverflow.  I just realized what you meant.  I'll try and accept some of my questions.  thx.

Comment: @tim_yates Yes, it's a tiny piece of XML, but the true XML is actually quite huge.  I'm want to detect if this "request" or "response" is in the ignore list.  If it is, then I'm not going to log req/resp accordingly.  I want to ignore logging of requests if the primary header tag exists.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution:

```
shouldIgnore = list.inject(false) { bool, val -> bool || line.contains(val) }
```

Whether or not this is the best idea depends on information we don't have; it may be better to do something more-XMLy rather than checking against a string.